# what is the format of this timestamp - "1369158405"?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, timestamp

What is the timestamp format for this - `"1369158405"`?

This link http://www.timestampgenerator.com/ provides such formats but I could not find any information on the format name.

I am also curious to know how such a timestamp is calculated to generate a format of type `"1369158405"` for `"Tue May 21 17:46:45 2013 GMT"`? Is there any function that creates such time stamps in C#?

Comment: Isn't that just a normal [unix epoch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time)?

Comment: +1 Thanks Oded. After reviewing the answers below, I realized it is unix epoch

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's a Unix Timestamp: the number of seconds that have elapsed since midnight Coordinated Universal Time (UTC), 1 January 1970

There is no built-in function in C# to create a Unix Timestamp. But this should do the trick:

```
public static double ConvertToUnixTimestamp(DateTime value)
{
    var span = (value - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0).ToLocalTime());
    return span.TotalSeconds;
}
```

If you want to truncate the milliseconds, cast the result as a `long`:

```
var timestamp = (long)ConvertToUnixTimestamp(DateTime.Now)
```

Comment: +1 Thanks for the short and well written answer. However, I have a small issue with it. From what you mentioned, it is generating a format of type "1369166918.97064" I am not sure what are those digits after the decimal point and how to get rid of it to just have "1369166918" ?

Comment: I found a much simpler way for the coding part: epoch = (DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime().Ticks - 621355968000000000) / 10000000;

Comment: @archer: Just cast the result to a `long`. That will strip the digits after the decimal point.

Answer (score 1):

It is the epoch time format, that specifies time in number of second/millisecond passed after 1 st january 1970

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_%28reference_date%29

Answer (score 0):

[just another confirmation:]

If you click the link 'Follow us on Facebook' then the (user) name of that Facebook page is: **Unix Timestamp Generator**

So, it's most likely a Unix Timestamp.

[edit: removed the actual link, just to avoid looking like a spammer]

Comment: was this a answer or advertisement?

Comment: Good question, but: no, not an advertisement (at least not for any of my stuff). In fact, I do suspect the question to be an advertisement since it is so obvious.

Comment: @TheNail: No, the question is not an advertisement. I used the link as a reference to just show the format of what I was talking about.

Comment: Hey I'm not the one who started on advertisement ;-)